# wp-cli не может подключиться к бд

Tags: php, wordpress

Эти команды выполняются нормально и тулза вполне общается с БД.

```
wp core config
wp db create
```

после выполнения последней, начинает жаловаться

```
Error: Ошибка установки соединения с базой данных
```

Уже второй день пытаюсь разобраться и что-то не особо получается. 
Парадокс в том, что сам сайт на локальном хосте, у которого конфиг сгенерирован данной утилитой без нареканий обращается к бд и работает нормально. Вся беда в wp-cli.
El_capitan, mamp.

Comment: Может wp db create ломается потому что база уже есть?

Comment: Неа. wp db create создает как раз новую базу данных и нареканий к этому нет. К этой же базе потом сайт и подключается

Comment: ломается сам WP в момент выполнения? что в wp-config, error_log? htccess настроен?

Comment: wp-cli после генерации wp-config не может подключиться к бд. вот вся проблема